# Dynamic textbox creation in form

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I want to create a `TextBox` dynamically in form and retrieve its data and paste it into another TextBox in the same form when I click a button.

I used the following code for creating texboxes dynamically :

```
public int c=0;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string n = c.ToString();
    txtRun.Name = "textname" + n;

    txtRun.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 20 + (10 * c));
    txtRun.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 25);
    this.Controls.Add(txtRun);
}
```

I need the code for retrieving data from this TextBox

Comment: What have you tried to retrieve data from TextBoxes  ? You need to know that StackOverFlow ansewers won't do your job.

Comment: "I need the code" is not a good question. Please rephrase it or this question is likely to be closed. You need to tell us the problems you are experiencing. Can't you find the textbox in your other method? What specific TextBox is it that you cant get the text of, `txtRun`? How are you creating `txtRun` btw?

Answer (score 1):

You are not creating the `Textbox` instance in your routine:

```
    TextBox txtRun = new TextBox();
    //...
    string n = c.ToString();
    txtRun.Name = "textname" + n;

    txtRun.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 20 + (10 * c));
    txtRun.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 25);
    this.Controls.Add(txtRun);
```

When you need the content:

```
string n = c.ToString();

Control[] c = this.Controls.Find("textname" + n, true);
if (c.Length > 0) {
    string str = ((TextBox)(c(0))).Text;
}
```

Or cache your instance in a *private array* if you need frequent look-ups on it.

The routine assumes it get a `Textbox` in index 0. You should of course check for `null` and `typeof`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, you could use something like this:

```
string val = string.Empty;
foreach (Control cnt in this.Controls)
{
       if(cnt is TextBox && cnt.Name.Contains("textname"))
            val = ((TextBox)cnt).Text;
}
```

Although I don't see where you are making new instances of the `TextBox` when you are adding them to the form.